# How to upload video from octobercms media to AWS s3 bucket using drivers plugin? Getting error File missing from Request

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I had a issue while uploading video to s3. Getting File missing from Request. Apart from able to see s3 media in dashboard and able to upload image to s3 as well.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to request the image?

Comment: I just followed the steps suggested in document link - https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/mediamanager#amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

on CyberPanel I fixed it by following steps:

1. Added made sure PHP version I am using is the same for what is for my website, i.e. 7.3
2. Turned on file_uploads "ON" (Most important) (this is where everything started working good)
3. Adding upload_tmp_dir dir might work but for me turning on only file_uploads worked
4. Added /tmp directory to OpenLiteSpeed > Server Configuration > File Uploads